# Accessing the context (or the root object) passed to Handler.js Template

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a template like so

**Handlebars Template**

```
<script id="choose-player-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <label>Entity Name:</label>
      <input type="text" value="{{entityName}}"></input>
      <ul>
      {{#players }}
        <li><input type="checkbox" {{#if isSelected}}checked{{/if}}/>
            {{name}}
        </li>
      {{/players}}
      </ul>
      <input type="button" onclick="saveSelection()" value="Save Selection" style="width:150px;"></input>
</script>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var playersList = {players: [], entityName: "Name1"}; //I pass this to the handlebar template
</script
```

Lets say that I pass a object **playersList** to the Template. What syntax should I use to refer to that object inside the Handlebars Template. In short, how to access the root object passed in to Handlebar template.

**Edit :**
I actually sound confusing with the question above, so this edit. Actually, the template is working and displaying properly the list of players in the **ul li** list. That part is fine. There is an object **"playersList** that is passed to template and all the **players** in this object are displayed properly. However, I am changing the state of each players through the **checkbox**. Now, once the user is done with the changes, he clicks the **input button**, shown in the last line of template code. This invokes **saveSelection()** javascript function (not shown in above code). I wan't to pass the **this** object from the template, to this function.

Answer (score 0):

Your context is already set to the base when you pass that object in. I don't know of anyway to access the base object when you are inside of a loop. You may want to create a Helper function to handle some of your processing if you can't get it the way you want.

It looks like you want to iterate your players list. 
You can do `{{#each players}} {{this}} {{/each}}` if `players = ['joe', 'bob', 'jim']`.

Comment: In the template I have an <input type="button"/> in the end. It has an "onclick" event bound to a function saveSelection(). I want to pass the context object to the saveSelection() function as a parameter. I hope its clear now. Basically, how do we refer to the root(or context or the base) object inside the template. I don't know what name is used to refer that root object

Comment: So you're saying that the user should select which player(s) they want and when they click save, it should send all the select player objects to the function?

Comment: I am passing "playersList" object to template. See the javascript in the second block of code in my question. The "playersList" object contains players array. I wan't "playersList" object to be sent as parameter to the saveSelection() function (invoked through the last line of template).

Comment: I'm not sure you can just compile a JS object in the Arguments list of an event handler like that. You make want to give each player an ID and pass that ID into the method. You would have to make playersList a global var. You'd then grab the ID in the function and extract the selected player object out of the 'global' playersList.

Comment: This is what exactly I did. So you too share the same idea. The only argument against using this approach is exposing playersList as global. Otherwise, I have a working code now. I am closing this question. Thanks.